# Combining attribute groupings on Dynamics CRM 2011 Charts

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

If I have a list of appointments w/ status codes I want to create a pie chart of, is there a way to combine some of the status codes to make the chart more readable:

Example: I have status codes A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, C1, C2, C3, C4.  Is there a way via FetchXML that I can create groupings of all the A, all the B, and all the C status codes so the pie chart only has 3 sections?

Here is the existing code:

```
    <visualization>
  <visualizationid>{F312E947-987E-E111-8116-00155D825C08}</visualizationid>
  <name>This Week's Status Codes</name>
  <primaryentitytypecode>serviceappointment</primaryentitytypecode>
  <datadescription>
    <datadefinition>
      <fetchcollection>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
          <entity name="serviceappointment">
            <attribute groupby="true" alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0" name="statuscode" />
            <attribute alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" name="statuscode" aggregate="count" />
          </entity>
        </fetch>
      </fetchcollection>
      <categorycollection>
        <category alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0">
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" />
          </measurecollection>
        </category>
      </categorycollection>
    </datadefinition>
  </datadescription>
  <presentationdescription>
    <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="55,118,193; 197,56,52; 149,189,66; 117,82,160; 49,171,204; 255,136,35; 97,142,206; 209,98,96; 168,203,104; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83">
      <Series>
        <Series ShadowOffset="0" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Inside, PieDrawingStyle=Default" ChartType="pie">
          <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
        </Series>
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea>
          <Area3DStyle Enable3D="false" />
        </ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      <Legends>
        <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
      </Legends>
      <Titles>
        <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
      </Titles>
    </Chart>
  </presentationdescription>
  <isdefault>false</isdefault>
</visualization>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't aggregate separate types in charts.  Instead, create a separate field for this and map the data over properly.  An on-demand workflow can accomplish this data migration task pretty easily.